# Туда и сюда

Tags: значение-слов

Начну с того, что мне в сети попалась фотография страницы из учебника русского языка для японцев. Вот она:

[image]

Так вот, мне стало интересно: а действительно, есть ли в других языках аналоги слова "сюда" и какое у него значение? Можно подумать, что "сюда" - значит "ко мне", а "туда" - куда-то в другое место. Но тут же можно вспомнить, скажем, такое предложение: "Разбиваем на сковородку два яйца, солим, сюда же добавляем колбасу". Но в данном случае с тем же успехом можно сказать и "туда". Либо тот случай, что показан на картинке. Куда шел персонаж диалога?
Прошу прощения за поток сознания, но интересно было бы разобраться в этих словах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть "здесь", и есть "там". "Здесь" обычно ближе, чем "там". И вот герои этого диалога идут сначала сюда, потом туда. Или наоборот.

В некоторых контекстах это синонимы. А в некоторых — антонимы: если ты туда, то я сюда.